# Как написать негативный тест?

Tags: юнит-тесты, phpunit

Как написать негативный тест, в котором хочу отметить, что если `count($jsonToArrayAll)` не равно 2, это ложь.

```
$this->assertFalse(assertNotEquals(2, count($jsonToArrayAll)));
```

Comment: "это ложь" - что значит? Вы должны проверять равно ли `count($jsonToArrayAll)` двум или нет и больше ничего. Т.е. либо `$this->assertNotEquals(2, count($jsonToArrayAll))`, либо `$this->assertFalse(2 == count($jsonToArrayAll));`

Answer (score 2):

`assertNotEquals()` - процедура, а не функция - она не возвращает ничего. Соответственно `assertFalse()` не будет срабатывать так, как ожидается.

Правильно так(любой из этих assert'ов):

```
// проверяет, что всё условие не верно
$this->assertFalse(2 == count($jsonToArrayAll)); 

// проверяет, что count($jsonToArrayAll) не равно 2 
$this->assertNotEquals(2, count($jsonToArrayAll));
```

Comment: Это все понятно, но мне нужно проверить с негативной стороны, на самом деле count($jsonToArrayAll) равно 2 , со словам можно сказать, что если count($jsonToArrayAll) не равно 2 это false. (то есть отрицательно)

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan, ну значит надо наоборот: либо `assertTrue`, либо `assertEquals`, вы пытаетесь сделать что-то непонятное

Comment: @BOPOH  $this->assertFalse(assertNotEquals(2, count($jsonToArrayAll))); об это что скажете?

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan, я написал все в комменте к вопросу: либо одно, либо другое. У вас не должно быть мыслей сделать что-либо другое, т.к. эти два варианта полностью покрывают все возможные варианты